# Length of minimum substring to delete

Tags: string, algorithm

Assume we have got two strings, let's call them `s1` and `s2`. Now, we want to delete such substring from `s2`, that `s2` would be a subsequence of `s1` after it and the length of deleted string is minimal.

For example, for for `s1 = "abbcabaa"` and `s2 = "accbccbaa"` such string is `cbcc` - after deleting it from `s2` we are left with `acbaa`, which is a subsequence of `s1`. It's length, `4`, is minimal.

Another example - `s1 = "abcaacb"`, `s2 = "adacaa"`. Such string is then `"da"` - we are left with `acaa` after deleting it, which is a subsequence of `abcaacb`. It's length `2` is minimal.

Any thoughts of solving th

Comment: The [Wagner Fischer algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagner%E2%80%93Fischer_algorithm) would probably be a good starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved in O(n+m), where n is the length of one string and m the length of the other.

You can do this by having a pointer on the first character of s1 and one on the first character of s2. Now if the characters are the same move both pointers forward, otherwise only the pointer for s1. This will generate the best result for removing shortest substring at the end. Now repeat the same procedure in reverse.

```
s1:                           abbcabaa
match s2 from beginning:      a  c    cbccaa
match s2 from the end:   accbc   c baa
```

Each time a character matches you save the indices. Here we would have the following two lists:

```
from beginning (a): [[0, 0], [1, 3]]
from the end   (b): [[8, 7], [7, 6], [6, 5], [5, 3]]
```

Now you can calculate the best result for removing the substring in the middle of the string by using two pointers again. Start with the first element in a and the last element in b, move forward step by step in a and backwards in b until the index for s1 in b is greater than the one in a. At each step calculate length of substring that has to be removed. And keep track of the minimum.

1st step: pa = [0, 0], pb = [5, 3], so substring from index 1 to 4 (inclusive) has to be removed (ccbc)

2nd step: pa = [1, 3], pb = [6, 5], substring from index 2 to 5 has to be removed (cbcc)

Finally we can see that there are two optimal solutions with length 4: ccbc and cbcc.

And here the same thing translated to code:

```js
// returns [startIndex (inclusive), endIndex (exclusive)]
function minSubstr(s1, s2) {
    let p2 = 0, a = [], b = []
    for (let p1 = 0; p1 < s1.length; p1++)
        if (s1[p1] == s2[p2]) {
            if (p2 + 1 == s2.length)
                return [0, 0] // no removal needed, s2 is subsequence of s1
            a.push([p1, p2++])
        }
    let best = [p2, s2.length]
    p2 = s2.length - 1
    for (let p1 = s1.length - 1; p1 >= 0; p1--)
        if (s1[p1] == s2[p2])
            b.push([p1, p2--])
    if (best[1] - best[0] > p2 + 1)
        best = [0, p2 + 1]
    let pb = b.length - 1
    for (let pa = 0; pa < a.length; pa++) {
        while (pb >= 0 && b[pb][0] <= a[pa][0])
            pb--
        if (pb < 0)
            break
        if (b[pb][1] - a[pa][1] - 1 < best[1] - best[0])
            best = [a[pa][1] + 1, b[pb][1]]
    }
    return best
}

let s1 = "abbcabaa", s2 = "accbccbaa"
console.log("s1 = " + s1); console.log("s2 = " + s2)
let best = minSubstr(s1, s2)
console.log("best = " + best + " (" + s2.substring(best[0], best[1]) + ")")
s1 = "abcaacb"; s2 = "adacaa"
console.log("s1 = " + s1); console.log("s2 = " + s2)
best = minSubstr(s1, s2)
console.log("best = " + best + " (" + s2.substring(best[0], best[1]) + ")")
```